# Why WCF service change date value in case different TimeZone on client and server side

Tags: asp.net, wcf, telerik, asp.net-4.5

I have WCF service, one service method return array of some objects, single object contain some date values, for example *{14-05-2013 08:00:00} Kind: Unspecified.* 
I can see in debug mode this value before return point in method.

On cleint side I getting JSON object that contain  **wrong date** value for my property: 
*Date(1368511200000+0200)*
it is equal to *Tue May 14 2013 09:00:00 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)*

it happens just in case when client (browser) and IIS server in different time zones.

Why I see shifted date values and how fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: And what exactly is wrong about the date/time? Which timezone is your server in? I would suspect it's GMT+2?

Comment: I would like to see time without changes, on server time zone Server TimeZone:(UTC+01:00), Client TimeZone:(UTC+02:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date values stay the same, but the presentation shifts because your timezone changes.

08:00 in Berlin *is* 07:00 in London.

If you want to transfer the same *presentation* regardless of the fact that it's no longer the same instant in time once this presentation crosses time zones, you could send it as string instead of date.

You could also change the [kind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx) of your DateTime to UTC, but that would have implications on your server side as well.

More information about time zone conversion is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397769.aspx).